# How to get ajax response in react?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, axios

I did a lot of research on how to get AJAX response and show it on the page but still no luck. I'm using `axios` and when I do `console.log(response.data)` I can see the response, but I'm struggling on how to present it on the page.

Here's my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Test extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        person: {
            name: "Mike",
            lastname: "Brown",
            response: []
        }
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data)
            console.log(response.data[0].title)
        self.setState({ response: response.data});
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{this.state.person.name}</h1>
            <ul>
                {
                    this.state.person.response.map((eachItem) => {
                        return (
                            <li>
                                {eachItem.title}
                            </li>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </ul>

        </div>


    );
 }

}
export default Test;
```

Comment: State is an explicit thing you need to set in your constructor.  this.person = ..... should be `this.state = { person: ....}` . And your render function should extract person from this.state. [state docs at fb](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class)

Comment: In your .then() response handler,  you either need to use an arrow function,  or bind the function explicitly.  `this` is not referring to the react component otherwise.    () => {}  will auto bind to the context it is defined in.  Otherwise function(response) { ..... }.bind(this)

Comment: Sorry, SO isn't a debugging place. Try to follow some tutorial you can find over the web.

Comment: Your setState is also setting a top level key of "response" but your component state has no such key.  You need to set a whole new person object,  with the correct response nested.   Right now your state after the get call would be `{ person: { name: 'mike', lastname: 'brown', response: [] }, response: ActualResponseHere }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look something like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


class Test extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      person: {
        name: "Mike",
        lastname: "Brown",
        response: []
      }
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ 
          person: Object.assign({}, this.state.person, { response: response.data })
        });
    });
}

render() {
    const person = this.state.person;
    debugger; // Run the code with your console open and see what
              // this.state.person looks like.  Make sure render is
              // called at least twice (this debugger should stop 
              // execution each time it's hit.
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{person.name + " " + person.lastname}</h1>

            <ul>
                {
                    person.response.map((eachItem, idx) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={`item-${idx}`}>
                                {eachItem.title}
                            </li>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

}
export default Test;
```

Comment: why do you have ...currentPerson inside of componentDidMount ?

Comment: Just preventing the line from being too long.  Also trying to show that state should be immutable,  so you want to spread out (via the ... spread operator,  or you can use Object.assign({}, currentPerson) ) the existing state object (current person in this case), update that with the response,  then setState.

Comment: I tried your code but no success

Comment: @progx - Updated code to add unique key's to the iterated `<li>` nodes.  Shouldn't prevent this from working but you'd see an error in the console about it.  If the console.logs are showing a person this should be pretty close to what you need.

Comment: I copied your code and got this error: bundle.js:22508 Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (25:30)

Comment: Updated to use Object.assign() instead of spread syntax. That doesn't mean there isn't a syntax error.

Comment: It worked now! thanks! not sure why it didn't work with the spread operator, any ideas why?

Comment: Spread operator is a new ES 2015 feature.  You need babel with the es2015 preset and webpack etc. to use it.

Comment: got it, I just voted it up and now marking it as the correct one. Thanks a lot bro!